# Brightness Controls Serious Lag Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: brightness, 15.04

I have a Asus N56v Laptop, recently upgraded to Vivid and now my Brightness Controls accessed via (<kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>, <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd>, <kbd>FN</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) have a dramatic lag. I can wait 30 up to 120 seconds before the keystroke is registered and the system adjusts.

I initially didn't think they were working at all, after spamming the keys it took 10 minutes to finish adjusting. The Volume keys configured the same way with fn+f10 work just fine and quickly.

This isn't the first time I have run into issues with the brightness controls either. They worked perfectly on Ubuntu 14.04 but stopped working all together in 14.10 and now they work but with extreme latency.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem now. My brightness controller was running fine on Ubuntu 14.10. But recently u upgraded to Vivit and now it's extreme laggy like you said. I have a 4th gen laptop.
I think the kernel is responsible somehow for our graphic cards driver because when i upgraded to Linux Kernel 3.19 on Ubuntu 14.10 i got the same issue and then i reverted back to the original one. But now 15.04 is using kernel 3.19 which may be causing this problem.
Maybe someone has a solution for us :)